# Setting up a UITabBarController with nib ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, uitabbarcontroller

Ok stuck on this one, help would be most appreciated.

So I have a tab controller inside a navigation controller in my storyboard.

Then I have two view controllers with nib files that I want to load into the tab controller programmatically. I'm using the following code but getting a blank screen when I load the app.

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    delegate = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let verbViewController = VerbViewController(nibName: "VerbViewController", bundle: nil)
    let communityViewController = CommunityViewController(nibName: "CommunityViewController", bundle: nil)

    let tabIcon1 = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "VerbTab"), tag: 0)
    let tabIcon5 = UITabBarItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "CommunityTab"), selectedImage: nil)


    verbViewController.tabBarItem = tabIcon1
    communityViewController.tabBarItem = tabIcon5

    let tabControllers = [verbViewController, communityViewController]
    self.tabBarController?.setViewControllers(tabControllers, animated: true)
    self.viewControllers = tabControllers
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Delegate method
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `self.tabBarController` from within a `UITabBarController` which doesn't make much sense.

`UIViewController`'s `tabBarController` returns "The nearest ancestor in the view controller hierarchy that is a tab bar controller." which in your case is probably nil because your tab bar controller is not contained in yet another tab bar controller.

You probably want to just call `self.setViewControllers` directly.

This behavior would also probably make more sense in `viewDidLoad` rather than `viewWillAppear`, do you really want to replace the controllers for each tab every time the tab bar appears?

Comment: Not to sure why I put it in viewWillAppear actialy.

Comment: Not ti sure why I put it in viewWillAppear. Even when I switch to self.setViewControllers it still loads a blank screen. Maybe I need to set something up in the view controllers class?

Comment: I can't offer more based on the code I can see. When you say a "blank screen" I'm not sure if that means that your tab bar controller is never added to the window or if the view controllers for each tab are not loading the view you expect.

Comment: Forgot to link the class. Thanks for the help Jonah. Think I had just being working to long needed to take a break.